# Reuse xib in different screens

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I have 4 screens that have one almost the same view:

[image: View have inactive state]

[image: View have active state]

And one screen have the same view but with slightly different UI:

[image]

So, my question: Can I use one xib and adapt states (active, inactive) and change ui for different screen? How I can do it?

Comment: First create a separate xib for your view and then you can create a subclass of UIView which will manage other things. Then use that class in different screens.

Comment: Where you are struggling ?

Comment: @RahulVyas I created Xib. I added all buttons, and I want in different screens hide and show different buttons, and make it enabled or disabled. I don't understand how I can do it.

Comment: create a function inside the the view's subclass , send it the state ( may be enum type ) and change the look accordingly before adding it to it's superview

Comment: @KukhtoA if any answer helped you please mark the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of this kind of class

In Your .m file of custom XIB class if you are using objective-c.

```
- (void)foo:(NSString*)labelText andButtonText:(NSString*)buttonTitle {
  //Do your code here for some screen like change labels and button text
}

- (void)bar:(NSString*)labelText andButtonText:(NSString*)buttonTitle {
  //Do your code here for some another screen and change labels and button text
}
```

In Your .h file of custom XIB class if you are using objective-c.

```
- (void)foo:(NSString*)labelText andButtonText:(NSString*)buttonTitle;

- (void)bar:(NSString*)labelText andButtonText:(NSString*)buttonTitle;
```

In your view controller where you want to display the custom UI

Create an instance of your xib or add through interfacebuilder
And On your instance of custom class call the method as required.

Below is a class I've used in one of my project to get a clear understanding.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DYRateView.h"

@interface LevelAndRankDetails : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView* contentView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView* viewContainer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* lblLevel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* lblRanking;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet DYRateView *viewRate;

- (void)setLevel:(NSNumber*)level andRanking:(NSNumber*)ranking;
- (void)setupUI;
@end
```

.m File

```
#import "LevelAndRankDetails.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation LevelAndRankDetails

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]){
        [self commonSetup];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self)
    {
        [self commonSetup];

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
}

- (void)viewFromNibForClass {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[[self class] description] owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.contentView];
    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
}

- (void)commonSetup {

    [self viewFromNibForClass];

    //For View's Corner Radius
    self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 12;
    self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = kDefaultBackgroundGreyColor;
    self.viewContainer.backgroundColor = kDefaultBackgroundGreyColor;//[UIColor clearColor];
    self.backgroundColor = kDefaultBackgroundGreyColor;
    //self.viewContainer.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xBB9657);//[kLearnFromLightColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

    self.viewRate.rate = 0;
    self.viewRate.editable = NO;
    self.viewRate.delegate = nil;
    self.viewRate.alignment = RateViewAlignmentCenter;
    self.viewRate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.viewRate setEmptyStarImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmpty"]];
    UIImage* imageFullStar = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFull"] imageTintedWithColor:kSliderDarkYellowColor];
    [self.viewRate setFullStarImage:imageFullStar];
    self.lblLevel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.lblRanking.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //For Teacher label
}

- (void)setupUI {
    self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
    self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.viewContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];//[UIColor clearColor];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

- (void)setRanking:(CGFloat)ranking {
    self.viewRate.rate = ranking;
}

- (void)setLevel:(NSNumber*)level {
    self.lblLevel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level : %@",level];
}

- (void)setLevel:(NSNumber*)level andRanking:(NSNumber*)ranking {

    if (level.integerValue > 0) {
        [self setLevel:level];
    }
    if (ranking.doubleValue > 0) {
        CGFloat rankingConverted = ranking.floatValue;
        [self setRanking:rankingConverted];
    }
}


@end
```

And this is how you use it in your view controller

```
LevelAndRankDetails* toolTipCustomView = [[LevelAndRankDetails alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 66)];
    toolTipCustomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [toolTipCustomView setLevel:@(10) andRanking:@(3)];
```